# df.corr() does not work. it just considers one feature column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, correlation

[df.corr() result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9Myq.png)I wonder if someone could help me to solve my problem. I have a data frame called: df_normalized that is a normal data frame with 17 columns. I want a correlation matrix based on spearman method to find if the feature columns are correlated with each other?
However, df_normalized.corr(method='spearman') just considers sex column as you can see in the uploaded pictures of my codes.[the data frame[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EIt0.png)

Comment: Please edit your post and add the data type of each column in your dataframe (`df.dtypes`).

Comment: @AlexK  thanks man, I was making the codes and information ready for you, and  just exported the data frame as an excel file and read it again as a data frame, it now works perfectly!!!

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if you could post the full code and at least part of the dataframe so it's easier to see what's wrong. It looks like there's only the sex column in your dataframe, but it's hard to tell.

You can find a nice example of how to do what you want here: https://datatofish.com/correlation-matrix-pandas/

Comment: thanks man, I was making the codes  ready for being shared, and just exported the data frame as an excel file and read it again as a data frame, it now works perfectly!!!

Comment: you're welcome, make sure to mark my answer as correct!